# CakePHP 3: Database syntax error or access violation issue

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have the following code which runs fine in a vagrant environment, but fails in the server. Can't figure out why.

```
$settingsQuery = $this->Configurations->find()
                ->select([
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'value',
                    'description',
                    'editable',
                    'keyPrefix' => "SUBSTR(name FROM 1 FOR POSITION('.' IN name) - 1)"
                ])->order('name');
```

if I comment out this part `//'keyPrefix' => "SUBSTR(name FROM 1 FOR POSITION('.' IN name) - 1)"` the code executes without issues. Something is wrong with this, but just on the server, not at the local dev.

I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am running CakePHP 3.4 on PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.6 on an Ubuntu box.

The SQL query generated by my vagrant setup (dev) runs well when tried thru phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT Configurations.id AS `Configurations__id`, Configurations.name AS `Configurations__name`, Configurations.value AS `Configurations__value`, Configurations.description AS `Configurations__description`, Configurations.editable AS `Configurations__editable`, SUBSTR(name FROM 1 FOR POSITION('.' IN name) - 1) AS `keyPrefix` FROM settings_configurations Configurations ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Enabled query logging on your MySQL server, and check what SQL exactly arrives there.

Comment: @ndm I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Then you can print sql by `dump($this->getLastSql())` and copy the Sql  deal in Sql environment.Then you can get the Error.

Comment: I have given up on a solution as it seems weird. I have resorted to pulling the keyPrefix using PHP